# How to load least significant digit of a register into variable? Getting "64 bit does not support 32-bit absolute addresses" on macho64

Tags: assembly, nasm, 32bit-64bit, mach-o

I want to display the least significant digit with an assembly program on nasm/macho-64:

```
%define SYSCALL_WRITE 0x2000004
%define SYSCALL_EXIT  0x2000001

SECTION .data
   digit db 0,10 

SECTION .text
   global _start

_start:

   add rax, 48
   mov [digit], al

   mov rax, SYSCALL_WRITE
   mov rdi, 1
   mov rsi, digit
   mov rdx, 2  ;length (of 48)
   syscall

   mov rax, SYSCALL_EXIT
   mov rdi, 0
   syscall
```

Here, al is used because it contains the lowest order byte of `rax`. I figured out from similar questions that 64-bit assembly doesn't have the `[]` syntax. I then tried to use

`lea digit, al`

and

`lea [digit], al`

but both gave me "invalid combination of opcode and operation" error. I also tried `mov rax` instead of `add rax`. What should I do in order to load/move the least significant digit of `rax` into my `digit` variable?

Thank you.

Comment: Add `default rel` to the top of the file or use `[rel digit]`. PS: your code will not give you the least significant digit unless your number is single digit (i.e. 0-9). Also, what do you expect to find in `rax` at process start? Maybe you forgot to initialize it?

Comment: `lea` will only calculate address and store it into register, it will never contact memory chip, so it definitely can't be used to read or write value from/to memory. I.e. `mov rax,[rax+rdx*8]` loads value from memory, and `lea` with same operands `lea rax,[rax+rdx*8]` will only calculate the address of memory, and put that into `rax`, instead of loading value from there. It's like first stage of `mov`, before contacting memory chip. ... throwing out random instructions will not help in assembly at all, keep re-reading the instruction descriptions and experimenting in debugger, till it's clear

Comment: @Jester Thanks! it worked. And yeah, this isn't the whole code – it's just a subroutine. I'll initialise `rax` in my `main` routine and then call `_start`

Comment: Don't use the name `_start` for anything other than your actual entry point.  In MacOS X, you can only write `_start` yourself in a statically-linked executable; the dynamic linker runs the CRT startup code and calls your entry point as `main`.  (Unlike on Linux).